# Jquery Animate lasting for certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I am trying to have jQuery animate function only last for a couple seconds and the revert back to the original item.

```
<button id="clickMe"> Click </button>
<div id="target"> Target </div>
```

and the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('#target').animate({opacity: 0.1}, 'slow');
  });
});
```

How would I make this effect only last for say two seconds? Thanks

Comment: you have duration in .animate() have you checked

Comment: See the second parameter of the animate() function: http://api.jquery.com/animate

Comment: Do you mean you want the opacity to stay at 0.1 for two seconds after it has been faded out and then revert the opacity to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This help you :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        $('#target').animate({opacity: 0.1}, 2000).animate({opacity: 1});
          });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting a time duration like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#clickMe').click(function() {
      $('#target').animate({
          opacity: 0.1
      }, 2000, function() {
          $('#target').animate({
             opacity: 1
          })
      });
   });
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66vodwLv/)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This help you:

```
$( "#target" ).animate({ opacity: 0.1 }, 2000, function() {
// Revert back.
});
```

Comment: Please add some additional information to supplement your code, ex what you changed and why it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use duration and complete options of animate

```
 $('#clickMe').click(function(){
   $('#target').animate(
     {opacity: 0.1},
    {
     duration: 2000,complete: function(){
     $('#target').css("opacity", 1);
    }});
});
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/d3135325X3R9QkzZjdbz?p=preview